# The vocabulary of first class functions

Tags: python-3.x, first-class-functions

When people say that Python, for instance, has first class functions, it makes it sound like Python also has second class functions. However, I've never yet (knowingly) encountered a second class function in Python. When we say this, does it really mean "All Python functions are first class?" Or is there an example of a second class function in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to clarify the nomenclature.

The term "first class functions" means that it is "first class" in the type system: that is, that functions themselves are values. In languages where functions are not first class, functions are defined as a relationship between values, which makes them "second class".

Put another way, "first class" functions implies that you can use a function as a value, which means (among other things) that you can pass functions into functions. You couldn't do this in Java before Java 7 (reflection doesn't count), so that's an example of a programming language only having "second class" functions. In order to "pass a function", you had to define a type where that function could live (as a method), and then pass an instance of that type.

So, in Python, *all* functions are first class, because *all* functions can be used as a value.

Now, there is another concept which you might be getting confused with. There is also a concept of a "higher order function". A higher order function is a function that takes a function as an argument. Not all functions in Pythons are higher-order, because not all functions take another function as an argument. But even the functions that are not higher-order are first class. (It's a square/rectangle thing.)

Comment: Okay, so in general whenever one hears "language X has first class functions" one should understand that to mean "All functions in X are first class."

Comment: Yes, because "language X has first class functions" is a statement about how the language's type system conceives of functions. It's a statement about functions as a concept within the language.

Comment: BTW, after thinking about it a bit more, I think you could argue that Ruby has first class functions without all functions being first class. In order for functions to be consumed as functions, they need to be converted into one of the function types before being passed in. https://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby

Although, at that point, you're parsing a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when we say "language X has first-class functions", we actually mean that "language X treats functions as first-class" (just like it does with other types). It usually means that you can pass functions as arguments, store them in arrays, etc.

I don't see any reason why a particular language (that treated functions as first-class) would *also* have second-class functions (i.e. those that *couldn't* be passed as arguments), but can't say whether Python does or doesn't.